# converting formatted json object to array of objects by keys

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a very generic that may be a common case when processing json data to some other format, such as:

```js
json = {
  "Title1": {
    "a1": {
      "key1": "val1",
      "key2": "val2",
      "key3": "val3"
    },
    "a2": {
      "key1": "val1",
      "key2": "val2",
      "key3": {
        "key4": "val4"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

into a array format such as:

```
var arr = [{
      "name": "Title1",
      _children: [{
          "name": "a1",
          _children: [{
              "name": "key1",
              "value": "val1"
            },
            {
              "name": "key2",
              "value": "val2"
            },
            {
              "name": "key3",
              "value": "val3"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "a2",
          _children: [{
              "name": "key1",
              "value": "val1"
            },
            {
              "name": "key2",
              "value": "val2"
            },
            {
              "name": "key3",
              _children: [{
                "name": "key4",
                "value": "val4"
              }]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

The logic applies recursively to any bottom level, so the final product will be an array like above.

I cannot think of how to implement this, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: What have tried?

Comment: Search for Object.keys and recurse

Comment: did you try JSON.parse()  ... or are you trying to hard code it?

Comment: never want to hard code it. the difficulty was to create the same structures on each level same as the original obj, which can be solved by using flatMap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and recursion

```js
let json = {"Title1":{"a1":{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2","key3":"val3"},"a2":{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2","key3":{"key4":"val4"}}}}

function recur(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj).flatMap(([key, val]) => {
    let o = { name: key }
    if(typeof val === 'object')  o._children = recur(val)
    else o.value = val      
    return [o]
  })
}

console.log(recur(json))
```